# Create a clock with separate SVG images

Tags: jquery, html, svg, html5-canvas, jquery-svg

I have two separate images. One is the clock without the arrow and the other is the clock arrow. Both are SVG images (vector).

I need to create like a clock in a Web Application where the 360 spin of the arrow depends on a time variable. For example if the time variable = 2 minutes then the arrow has to spin the complete circle in 2 minutes.

Here are the sample images:

[image]

What is the best approach to do this?

- HTML5 Canvas
- jQuery

Comment: Neither.  Just CSS.

Comment: How can I do that with just CSS? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The images you provided aren't vector, nor are they separate, but here is the basic idea:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjlyA.png);
  background-size: cover
}

div div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjlyA.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top right;
  animation: rot 2s linear 0s infinite;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

@keyframes rot {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="animation-duration: 5s"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing Robert, how can I make it stop once it spin 360? I mean I just need it to go once the 360 and stop. Appreciate so much Im impressed

Comment: Change `infinite` to `1`.